# Possitioning popup windows.create

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

The `top` and `left` properties in `windows.create` does not position the window. It is always positioned in center.

Two questions:

1. I can add a procedure to position the window after it is open by using `browser.windows.update()` but was wondering why it does not work as it is.
2. I would like to have it non-modal. Is this possible? I notice the popup returned has `alwaysOnTop: false`, but it is always on top. I am porting an old Chrome project - in Chrome the window is not modal.

On a side note: There also seems to be some inconsistency related to the popup returned from the `create` call.

- `type` is *"popup"* when using both popup and panel.
- `left` and `top` are sometimes `0` and other times has the actual value. Seems like when using `popup` as type the position is more often `0`.

Example:

**manfiest.json**:

```js
{
    "name"              : "Test winpos",
    "short_name"        : "ext_name_short",
    "version"           : "0.0.0.1",
    "author"            : "NW",
    "manifest_version"  : 2,
    "browser_action"    : {
        "default_title" : "Test winpos"
    },
    "background"    : {
        "scripts"   : ["./bg.js"]
    }
}
```

**bg.js**:

```js
"use strict";

var dbg = 1;
var popup_id = -1;
// normal, popup, panel, detatched_panel
var type = "panel";

browser.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(w_id) {
    if (dbg) console.log(';; onRemoved, (w_id, popup_id):', w_id, popup_id);
    if (w_id === popup_id)
        popup_id = -1;
});
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (/* tab */) {
    if (dbg) console.log(';; onClicked, (popup_id):', popup_id);
    if (popup_id < 0) {
        browser.windows.create({
            allowScriptsToClose: true, // FF Only
            url     : browser.extension.getURL("popup.html"),
            type    : type,
            // FF NOT SUPPORTED focused : true,
            width   : 450,
            height  : 320,
            left    : 50,
            top     : 50
        }, function (pop) {
            if (dbg) console.log(`;; windows.create-> ${type}:`, pop);
            popup_id = pop.id;
            // I can add positioning call here
        });
    } else {
        if (dbg) console.log(';; window.update, (pupup_id)', popup_id);
        browser.windows.update(popup_id, { "focused": true });
    }
});
```

**popup.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test FF Popup</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </body>
</html>
```